# Tests fails when ran through testng.xml but passes when ran individually

Tags: java, maven, selenium, appium

I am trying to run all the test one by one using testng.xml file, but I keep getting Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

Here is the testng.xml file:
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Sample Suite" verbose="1" >
       <test name="Test" >
        <classes>
          <class name="packagename.test1"/>
          <class name="packagename.test2"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>`

This is the Error:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MGCWTTDEP01', ip: '##########', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver`

If I run test cases as testng Suite it fails, if I run it using testng test it run perfectly.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure but you might want to put the  tags `<test> ...</test>` inside `<tests>` tags like:  ```<tests> <test> ... </test> ... </tests>```

Comment: Are you using uiAutomator2?

Comment: @Muzzamil no I am not using uiAutomator2